# Add marker to a map and prevent adding another until previous one has been saved to database

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on an application using Google maps which allows a user to add a marker to a map. What I am trying to achieve is to only allow them to add one marker at a time and prevent them from being able to add another until the details of the the previous one have been saved to a database.

What I currently have works to a degree. It allows a user to add a marker. Once added they cant add another one.

They can drag the marker they have added around the map to a desired position and the details can be saved to a database using a form. What I want to achieve is to be able to add another marker when the form is submitted.

This is my code for adding the marker. It works perfectly as does the code for the form which adds it to the database

```
    //adds a listener that registers when the window has loaded
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function(){ 

    //hides the form for adding a service until the map is clicked
    $("#add_marker").hide();

    // adds a listener to the map that registers a click event
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {

    $("#add_marker").show(); // Shows the form for adding a service after the map is clicked
    //assigns the clicked position on the map to the variables var lat and var lng
    var lat = event.latLng.lat();
    var lng = event.latLng.lng();
    myCoordsLength = 6;

    //alert("Lat=" + lat + "; Lng=" + lng);
    });

   // populate the textfield inputs with lat, lng coordinates 

  /*eventlistener for the map that registers a click event that gets the longitude and latitude of the event and adds a marker to the map at that position */
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  document.getElementById('input_lat').value =     event.latLng.lat().toFixed(myCoordsLength);
  document.getElementById('input_long').value = event.latLng.lng().toFixed(myCoordsLength);
  placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });

  var marker;
  //Configure the marker
  function placeMarker(location) { // open function

    if ( marker ) 
    {
        marker.setPosition(location);
    }

    else

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location, 
    map: map,
    draggable:true, // makes the marker dragable
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP, //adds an animation to the marker hen it first appears
    title:'new marker'
    });

  // add a listener for the "dragend" event
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {

  // Get the Current position, where the marker was dropped
  var point = marker.getPosition();

  // centers the map on markers coords
  //map.setCenter(marker.position);

  // Update the hidden form text boxes for latitude and longitude of the marker
  document.getElementById('input_lat').value = point.lat().toFixed(myCoordsLength);
  document.getElementById('input_long').value = point.lng().toFixed(myCoordsLength);

  });

  } // close function
  })
```

I am using the `if(marker)` statement or `addListenerOnce`to prevent the adding of another marker once the first one has been added but I am not sure how to counteract this after the form has been submitted and then allow the user to add another marker.

I used this in the end. It allows a user to add only one marker and move it around the map on the click event. It allows a user to use this marker to store multiple locations into the database. Its not a perfect solution but works does what I need it too.

```
    var marker; 

    function placeMarker(location) { 

    if ( marker ) 
    {
        marker.setPosition(location);
    }

    else

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location, 
    map: map,
    draggable:true, 
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,  
    title:'new marker'
    });
```

Comment: Problem solved I am just going to run with the `if(marker)` solution for now which prevents the adding of a new marker if there is one already on the map - I will keep digging for a more complete solution and will update if I find one

Comment: Used this in the end. It allows only one marker to be added        `var marker; function placeMarker(location) { 
        
        if ( marker ) 
        {
            marker.setPosition(location);
        }

        else

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location, 
        map: map,
        draggable:true, 
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,  to the marker when it first appears
        title:'new marker'
        });`